# Solving simple system of congruences

Tags: divisibility

I have this example from wikipedia:

$$x \equiv 3 \pmod 4$$
$$x \equiv 4 \pmod 5$$

$$x = 4a + 3\\
4a + 3 \equiv 4 \pmod 5\\
4a \equiv 1 \equiv -4 \pmod 5\\
a \equiv -1 \pmod 5\\
x = 4(5b - 1) + 3 = 20b - 1
$$

But wikipedia shows $20b + 19$...what did I do wrong here?

Comment: You have done everything right. $N \equiv -1 \equiv 19 (\mod 20)$

Comment: Oh, yeah, thanks :U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is equivalent since $\ 19 \equiv -1\pmod{20}.\ $ Explicitly $\ 20b\!+\!19 = 20(b\!+\!1)\!-\!1.\,$

Simpler: $\, x \equiv -1\, $ mod $\,4,5\ \Rightarrow\ x\equiv -1\,$ mod $\,{\rm lcm}(4,5) = 20,\ $ i.e. $\ 4,5\mid x\!-\!1\,\Rightarrow\, 4\cdot 5\mid x\!-\!1.$

Comment: Is there a faster way to solve such systems, in case I had more equations?

Comment: The above is one optimization of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) It often proves handy for small numbers. In general you need to resort to CRT, computing inverses by the extended Euclidean algorithm (or some equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

Generalization:

$a \equiv b(\mod n)$ if $b<n$, $a\equiv b-n (\mod n)$

The reason is quite simple, $a \equiv b-n (\mod n) \implies a+n \equiv b(\mod n)$